# Submit value to html textbox with awesomium - vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, awesomium

am using this code to split text from listbox :

```
For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
                TextBox2.AppendText(Item.ToString + Environment.NewLine)
            Next
            Dim str As String = TextBox2.Text
            Dim leftPart As String = str.Split(":")(0)
            Dim test As String = TextBox2.Text
            Dim phrase As String = test.Substring(test.IndexOf(":"c) + 1)
```

and this code to submit the value to html textbox

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('email').value=""" + leftPart + """;")
                Dim leftpar2 As String
                leftpar2 = phrase
                MsgBox(phrase)
                Try
                    WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('pass').value=""" + leftpar2 + """;")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
```

The textbox with id (email) work fine 
 
but the other one ( pass ) always get empty , I've tried to popup the value of ( phrase ) it get the correct value

I've tried to assign string to variable ( phrase )

```
Dim phrase As String = "test"
```

it work fine , can somebody tell me what am doing wrong ?

Comment: if the item in listbox is ( test:1234 ) 
leftpart = test 
phrase = 1234

Comment: What if you will try `.ExecuteJavascript("alert(' & leftpar2 & "')")`

Comment: yes I've tried it 
nothing happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have download that component and went through your way

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (TextBox1.Text.Length < 3 Or TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(":") < 1) Then
        MsgBox("Please type value in format like {email:password}")
        Return
    End If

    ' Get the values and parse it
    Dim sources As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(":")

    ' Now, we try to set it to page
    ' pay attention at `document.querySelector('#id')` it should be ID of the element
    WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#email').value = '{0}'", sources(0)))
    WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#password').value = '{0}'", sources(1)))
End Sub
```

And here's my login page code (the page which loads in WebControl component)

```
<body>
    <input type="email" id="email" /> 
    <input type="password" id="password" /> 
    <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
</body>
```

Everything seems to be working

*You can run my example: drop textbox, webcontrol and button on form, set WebControl1.Source as 'http://cafe-ht.ml/fake/fake-login.html' and copy handler on button click*

[image]

Comment: I'am using it on https://facebook.com/login.php 
still the same error , I can't submit the value to textbox with id ( pass ) 
  WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#email').value = '{0}'", sources(0)))
        WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#pass').value = '{0}'", sources(1)))


but  when 
I use this WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#pass').value = '{0}'", "test")) 
it work fine

Comment: why the first code with ( source(1) ) did not worked ?

Comment: I tried it on you're link 
it did not worked also 
it maybe the problem with web-control

Comment: Seems so, I using vse2013 for windows, on windows 8.1, latest version of awesomium

Comment: cafe-ht.ml/downloads/WindowsApplication2.zip

Comment: Yes Thanks That worked perefect 
any way I founded the problem